# Display textbox multiple row values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a `Category` dropdown selection and `Mobile_Number` text field. Based on my Category selection, Mobile textbox fetches DB values.

My problem is that sometimes the same Category has two or more Mobile textbox values. In this case, I want all mobile number values to be displayed in a single textbox separated by a comma (`,`).

Sample Table Data

```
Mobile_Number  Category
  123            IT
  345            IT
  456            IT
```

In this case when the 'IT' category is selected, then I want to display output in the text box like this below:-

```
123,345,456
```

My working code:

Ajax Page Code:

```
$departid = $_POST['depart'];   // department id    
$sql = "SELECT Mobile_Number FROM admin_panel WHERE Category=".$departid;    
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);    
$users_arr = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  //$userid = $row['Emp_Id'];
  $name = $row['Mobile_Number'];
  //$users_arr[] = array("id123" => $userid, "name123" => $name);
  $users_arr[] = array("name123" => $name);
}
echo json_encode($users_arr);
```

Dropdown and Textbox

```
<select name="cat" id="cat">
  <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
  <option value="1">Stencil Team</option>
  <option value="2">Tooling Team</option>
  <option value="3">IT</option>
  <option value="4">Manager</option>
</select>

<input name="phoneNumber" id="pnum" type="text">
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cat").change(function(){
    var deptid = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajaxdropdown.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: { depart: deptid },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        var len = response.length;                      
        $("#pnum").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i<len; i++) {
          var name1234 = response[i]['name123'];
          $("#pnum").val(name1234);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `success`-function has to be modified:

```
function(response){
    var len = response.length;
    var name1234 = "";                      
    $("#pnum").empty();
    for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
        name1234 += (name1234.length < 1) ? response[i]['name123'] : ',' + response[i]['name123'];
    }
    $("#pnum").val(name1234);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` to build an array of the returned `name123` values, then `join()` it together before setting it to the `val()` of the input. Something like this:

```
success: function(response) {
  var names = response.map(function() {
    return this.name123;
  });
  $("#pnum").val(names.join(',');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Don't need to execute while loop in AJAX page code you can use GROUP_CONCAT & GROUP BY in your query to get the multiple Mobile number comma separated.

Check below **AJAX Page** code

```
<?php
$departid = $_POST['depart'];   // department id
$sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Mobile_Number) AS mob_number FROM admin_panel WHERE 
Category='".$departid."' GROUP BY Category";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$name = $row[0];
echo json_encode($name);
?>
```

According to output of this code you also not require For loop in Javascript. You can just set the response of AJAX to **phoneNumber** field.

Javascript Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cat").change(function(){
    var deptid = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajaxdropdown.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: { depart: deptid },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
          $("#pnum").val(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you (PHP):

```
$numbers = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $numbers[] = $row['Mobile_Number'];
}

echo json_encode(implode(', ',$numbers));
```

and this to js:

```
success: function(response) {                    
    $("#pnum").empty().val(response);        
}
```